# Linking nodes in a cluster to run a single instance of a docker container

Tags: containers, docker-swarm, ubuntu

In this cluster, there are 11 identical nodes, each with 16gb of memory. So far, I've been able to connect each node of the cluster to a docker swarm hosted on the control node. My end goal is to run a single instance of a container that utilizes the resources of each node so the total memory of that container would be 176gb. How should I accomplish this?

Each worker node is running Ubuntu Server 20.04 and the control node is running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04, all with docker engine 19.03.8.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible with container orchestration. Containers are bound by host and cannot be larger than host machines.

At the same time, depending on your specific tasks there may exist specialized distributed software that may be suitable for your needs - i.e. Apache Spark covers a lot of computational use cases.